# Cannot redirect after HTTP headers have been sent in MCV3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I have used jQuery `$.ajax` call for getting partial view in mvc3. At same time I have used sessionfilter to check session time out. Once the session has time out, it returns to login page, but the login page is displayed within the partial page div instead of redirecting to the whole page. I tried the code below on global.ascx page to fix it, but it's not working. It throws the following error:

```
public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
        {
   filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Clear();
   filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Write("**custom error message**");
   filterContext.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode = 401;
   filterContext.HttpContext.Response.End();
}
```

The exception is given below

```
 at System.Web.HttpResponse.Redirect(String url, Boolean endResponse, Boolean permanent)
 at System.Web.HttpResponseWrapper.Redirect(String url, Boolean endResponse)
 at TransFlow.SessionExpireFilterAttribute.OnAuthorizationHelp(ActionExecutingContext filterContext) in D:\LocalSVN\INTELLAFLO\5_Source\branches\balasubramanian\TransFlow\TransFlow\Global.asax.cs:line 131
 at TransFlow.SessionExpireFilterAttribute.OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext) in D:\LocalSVN\INTELLAFLO\5_Source\branches\balasubramanian\TransFlow\TransFlow\Global.asax.cs:line 120
 at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodFilter(IActionFilter filter, ActionExecutingContext preContext, Func`1 continuation)
 at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass15.<>c__DisplayClass17.<InvokeActionMethodWithFilters>b__14()
 at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodFilter(IActionFilter filter, ActionExecutingContext preContext, Func`1 continuation)
 at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass15.<>c__DisplayClass17.<InvokeActionMethodWithFilters>b__14()
 at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodWithFilters(ControllerContext controllerContext, IList`1 filters, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters)
 at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeAction(ControllerContext controllerContext, String actionName)
 at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.ExecuteCore()
 at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerBase.Execute(RequestContext requestContext)
 at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerBase.System.Web.Mvc.IController.Execute(RequestContext requestContext)
 at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.<>c__DisplayClass6.<>c__DisplayClassb.<BeginProcessRequest>b__5()
 at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.<>c__DisplayClass1.<MakeVoidDelegate>b__0()
 at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.<>c__DisplayClass8`1.<BeginSynchronous>b__7(IAsyncResult _)
 at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End()
 at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.<>c__DisplayClasse.<EndProcessRequest>b__d()
 at System.Web.Mvc.SecurityUtil.<GetCallInAppTrustThunk>b__0(Action f)
 at System.Web.Mvc.SecurityUtil.ProcessInApplicationTrust(Action action)
 at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
 at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult result)
 at System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
 at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to do a redirect from the action filter or controller instead of writing directly to the response. This will avoid the page layout issue you are seeing.