# Auto-logout loading in partial view instead of top/parent

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-3

A data-collection site using MVC3 with jQuery and Ajax. The site is using tabs (jquery ui tabs), loaded as partials and each connected to ajax-forms. So each tab is loaded and submitted only within "itself".

But this creates a problem with the auto-logout and redirection to LogOn. The logout will fire when I, for example, press a new tab. This tab will then be rendered with the full LogOn-page, instead of refreshing the "parent/top" window. So the entire site is mirrored in one of the tabs (like often happens when using frames). The is no frame or iframe usage on the site though.

One way to perhaps solve it would be to itercept the ajax-call, maybe in the OnBegin, to check if the user is logged in. If not redirect the entire window url to /Account/LogOn. I'm not sure on how to accomplish this though, or if it's the best way to go. Any ideas on execution or tips for better handling of this?

Some code examples:

**Edit.cshtml, snippet: the tabs**

```
<div id="tabs">
<ul>
    <li><a href="@Url.Action("PatientGeneralTab", new { guid = @Model })"><span>General</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="@Url.Action("PatientVisitTab", new { guid = @Model })"><span>Visit</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="@Url.Action("PatientDiaryTab", new { guid = @Model })"><span>Treatment</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="@Url.Action("PatientReactionTab", new { guid = @Model })"><span>Adverse Drug Reaction</span></a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

**General.cshtml, partial, snippet: Ajax.BeginForm()**

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("StoreGeneral",
new { },
new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "POST", OnBegin = "Saving", OnSuccess = "SavedOk(); reloadPatientHeader();" },
new { id = "form-general" }))
{
    form content here.
}
```

**Web.config, authentication**

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <!-- TODO: Change back to 60 -->
  <forms loginUrl="/Account/LogOn" timeout="2" />
</authentication>
```

Not sure if I need to post any other code-snippets. If so just let me know.

**Edit**

I stumbled on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14036496/cannot-redirect-after-http-headers-have-been-sent-in-mcv3) that has similar problems to mine. But I can't add any code to the controllers since the entire controller-class is wrapped in "[Authorize(Roles="xxx,yyy")]", so the check for login happens before the actual controller actions.

I tried to intercept the call in the AccountController instead, under "LogOn", but then it just ends up in an infinite loop :)

```
    public ActionResult LogOn()
    {
        bool isAjaxRequest = Request.Headers["X-Requested-With"] == "XMLHttpRequest";
        if (isAjaxRequest && !Request.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            //Response.Headers["X-Requested-With"] = "";
            return RedirectToAction("LogOn");
        }
        return View();
    }
```

**The solution**

For reference, this is what I ended up using:

```
    public ActionResult LogOn()
    {
        bool isAjaxRequest = Request.Headers["X-Requested-With"] == "XMLHttpRequest";
        if (isAjaxRequest && !Request.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            return JavaScript("window.location = '/Account/LogOn'");
        }
        return View();
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using

```
Request.IsAjaxRequest()
```

to detect ajax requests. It's an extension method in System.Web.Mvc.

Or you can check manually:

```
bool isAjaxRequest = request.Headers["X-Requested-With"] == "XMLHttpRequest";
```

With this you can do your intercept and test for authentication, and act accordingly. You could either choose not to show layout or stop the whole request and send to login page instead.

Comment: Thanks @whoshotjr. It's a step in the right direction for sure, but when I add a check for this in the controller it won't get checked unless the user is logged in. If the user has been logged out due to inactivity the controller is "skipped" and the LogOn-page appears. The problem persist though in that the LogOn-page is now a sub-page under the tabs (a page-in-page scenario).

Comment: Your question edit shows you are now just redirecting your ajax call, and creating another ajax call, hence the looping. Instead you could send some javascript to the client to redirect it to a full postback to the login page. Just send a window.location using Scriptmanager.RegisterClientScriptBlock

Comment: Actually...my previous comment regarding Scriptmanager.RegisterClientScriptBlock may have been a web forms-y. Must remember this is MVC. LOL

Comment: I was just searching around on how to utilize that "...ScriptBlock". Any other ideas on how to call a "normal" url redirect from within the controller? Right now I'm trying: return JavaScript("window.location = '/Account/LogOn'");. But I would be surprised if it worked since the method is not expecting that output at all.

Comment: Actually, my last comment worked :) Had no idea an ActionResult could include only a javascript. Thanks for leading me in the right direction @whoshotjr